# Render three or two posts in each slide alternately in a Swiper slider

Tags: php, wordpress, swiper.js

I'm developing a WordPress plugin that renders a slider using the [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/) lib. I need to show three posts (odd slides) or two posts (even slides) in each slide alternately. This is the code I came up but it's not working as I expect to:

```
$posts = get_posts( $args );

$html = '<!-- Begin slider markup -->
    <div class="swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">';

// Counter to keep track of the posts
$post_counter = 0;

$posts_per_slide = 3;

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    // Start a new slide after every three or two posts
    if ( $post_counter % $posts_per_slide === 0 ) {
        $html .= '<div class="swiper-slide">';
    }

    $html .= '<article id="post-' . esc_attr( $post->ID ) . '" class="wp-post">
        <div class="wp-post-thumbnail">
        <a href="' . esc_url( get_the_permalink( $post->ID ) ) . '"><img src="https://placehold.co/1000x700" width="1000" height="700" /></a>
        <h2 class="wp-post-title">' . get_the_title( $post->ID ) . '</h2>
        </div>
        </article>';

    // Increment the post counter
    $post_counter++;

    // Close the slide after every three or two posts
    if ( $post_counter % $posts_per_slide === 0 ) {
        $html .= '</div>';
        $posts_per_slide = ( $posts_per_slide === 3 ) ? 2 : 3;
    }
}

$html .= '</div>
    </div>
    <!-- End slider markup -->';

echo $html;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't resetting your post counter in your second

`if ( $post_counter % $posts_per_slide === 0 ) {}` block.

- On first loop, you open the `swiper_slide` div, make the article, and increment `$post_counter`.
- On second loop, `$post_counter` is 1, incremented to 2.
- On third loop, `$post_counter` is 2, incremented to 3, which satisfies the second check, closes the `swiper_slide` div, and sets `$posts_per_slide = 2`.
- Your `$post_counter` is still set to 3.
- The next loop (post 4) then checks `3 % 2 === 0` which is `false`, and consequently doesn't open the next `swiper_slide` div.

Reset your `$post_counter` each time your second check is true, and you should be good.